# Absolute positioned div inside position:relative overflow:scroll div

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

We have a list of boxes with horizonal scrolling, like this:

[image]

```css
    

    ul {
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        flex: 0 0 24%;
        max-width: 24%;
        margin-right: 1.3%;
        margin-top: 3px;
        height: 140px;
        position: relative;
        color: #000000;
        white-space: normal;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .container {
        white-space: nowrap;
        background: #fff;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        height: 160px;
    }
    
    .cover {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 20px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    .box {
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
     <div class="cover">&nbsp;</div>
     <ul>
      <li class="box empty"></li>
      <li class="box gradient"></li>
      <li class="box gradient"></li>
      <li class="box gradient"></li>
      <li class="box gradient"></li>    
     </ul>
    </div>
```

How to make the "cover" div fixed on the right after the div has scrolled horizontally? At the moment it's stuck at the original position, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work, it is corrupted. Shows empty list.

Comment: Fixed, you can check it now

Comment: `How to make the "cover" div fixed on the right after the div has scrolled horizontally` what do you mean by that ? Can you elaborate better ?

Comment: Run the snippet in full page mode: the "cover" div is at the right of the div. Then try to scroll the items horizontally: you will see the "cover" div is not at the right anymore while I want it to be fixed at the right of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a potential solution but I needed to put the overflow onto the `<ul>`, move the "cover" after the `<ul>` and make the container `display: flex` as well. The "cover" is then just relatively positioned back over the `<ul>`.

I also added a `background-color` to show the "cover" better for the demo.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 24%;
  max-width: 24%;
  margin-right: 1.3%;
  margin-top: 3px;
  height: 140px;
  color: #000000;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: left;
}

.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #fff;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
}

.cover {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="box empty"></li>
    <li class="box gradient"></li>
    <li class="box gradient"></li>
    <li class="box gradient"></li>
    <li class="box gradient"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```